# Cypher Neo4j creating Relationship between two nodes and avoiding bidirectional relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here is my query:

```
   MATCH (a:Person)-[:friend]->(p:Person)<-[:friend]-(b:Person)
   WITH a, b, COUNT(p) as count
   WHERE count >= 2
   CREATE (a)-[:friend {new: "yes"}]->(b)
   RETURN a,b,count
```

I tried to find a and b that have at least 2 common friends and creating friend relationship between them. Here is the result sample:

```
   a             b            count
   name1         name2          3
   name2         name1          3
```

Notes that the result is repeated, and this will create a bi-directional relationship between them. name1-[:friend]->name2 also means name1<-[:friend]-name2, so if I created a bi-directional relationship, the relationship between them will be duplicated as shown in my csv file:

```
   a             b            relationship
   name1         name2           friend
   name1         name2           friend
   name2         name2           friend
   name2         name2           friend
```

Is there any way I can avoid this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, there's a trick to do this:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:friend]->(p:Person)<-[:friend]-(b:Person)
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b)
WITH a, b, COUNT(p) as count
WHERE count >= 2
CREATE (a)-[:friend {new: "yes"}]->(b)
RETURN a,b,count
```

The change is the `WHERE ID(a) < ID(b)` which makes sure that just one of the two directions is chosen

Comment: By the way, I picked up this trick from Nicole White's excellent screencast on recommendation engines in Neo4j: http://watch.neo4j.org/video/109169965

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I've been looking for. =)

Comment: Glad to hear it!  If it worked for you, please accept the answer

Comment: @BrianUnderwood i tried your suggestion. It worked!, but in my case at the beginning my query displayed 3 times the relation e.g.  Grid26 Grid19, Grid19 Grid26, Grid19 Grid26               And when i add the WHERE condition, it displays 2 times. I think there is something wrong with my query                                                          MATCH (g:Grid)<-[r:PICK_UP]-(:User) 
WITH g, count(r) as numRelations
WHERE numRelations <= 2 
WITH g 
MATCH (g)-[:TO]-(g2:Grid)<-[:PICK_UP]-(:User) 
WHERE ID(g) < ID(g2) 
RETURN g.name, g2.name